# SAS- Condensing Multiple Rows, Keeping highest Value

Tags: sas, multiple-columns

I'm trying to accomplish the following. I have tried using arrays and sorting but nothing appears to work.Any help would be appreciated.

```
Acct     Score1   Score2
9999       45       78
9999       58       65
8888       43       80
8888       43       90
8888       31       70

This is what I would like to end up with
Acct     Score1     Score2
9999       58         78
8888       43         90
```

So basically, keep the highest score for each account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `PROC MEANS`.

```
proc means data=have nway ;
  class acct ;
  var score1 score2 ;
  output out=want max= ;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!, exactly what I wanted to do

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend PROC SQL:

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE want AS 
        SELECT Acct, 
            MAX(Score1) AS Score1, 
            MAX(Score2) AS Score2
        FROM have
            GROUP BY Acct;
QUIT;
```