# SAS for the following scenario

Tags: sas, duplicates

Assume I have a data-set `D1` as follows:

```
ID    ATR1    ATR2    ATR3  
1     23      10      11
2     22      11      14
1     19      14      15
2     34      6       17
3     10      11      5
```

I want to create a data-set `D2` from this as follows

```
ID    ATR1    ATR2    ATR3  
1     23      14      15
2     34      11      17
3     10      11      5
```

In other words, Data-set `D2` consists of unique IDs from `D1`. For each ID in `D2`, the values of ATR1-ATR3 are selected as the maximum (of the respective variable) among the records in `D1` with the same ID. For example ID = 1 in `D2` has ATR1 = max(23,19) = 23.

I have one solution which is very clumsy. I simply sort copies of the data set `D1' three times (by ID and ATR1 e.g) and remove duplicates. I later merge the three data-sets to get what I want. However, I think there might be an elegant way to do this. I have about 20 such variables in the original data-set.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37911397/1919583

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROC SQL METHOD**

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE D2 AS
  SELECT ID,
  MAX(ATR1) as ATR1,
  MAX(ATR2) as ATR2,
  MAX(ATR3) as ATR3,
  FROM D1
  GROUP BY ID;
QUIT;
```

The `GROUP BY` clause can also be written `GROUP BY 1`, omitting `ID`, as this refers to the 1st column in the `SELECT` clause.

**PROC SUMMARY METHOD**

```
PROC SUMMARY DATA=D1 NWAY;
             CLASS ID;
             VAR ATR1 ATR2 ATR3;
             OUTPUT OUT=D2 (DROP=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) MAX()=;
RUN;
```

Here's an explanation of some of the options:

- `NWAY` - gives only the maximum level of summarisation, here it's not as important because you have only one `CLASS` variable, meaning there is only one level of summarisation. However, without `NWAY` you get an extra row showing the max value of `ATR1-ATR3` across the whole dataset, which is not something you asked for in your question.
- `DROP=_TYPE_ _FREQ_` - This removes the automatic variables:

  - `_TYPE_` - which shows the level of summarisation (see comment above), which would just be a column containing the value `1`.
  - `_FREQ_` - gives a frequency count of the `ID` values, which although useful, isn't something you wanted in your question.